# How to loop through the keys and values stored in a Spring HashMap model within a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a method in my Spring Controller:

```
public ModelAndView testRoCompliance(@RequestParam String regOfficeStr) {
    Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();
    results.put("inputs", "an input");
    results.put("result", "the answer");
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("simpleOutput", results);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And I have a JSP that can print the variables:

```
<body>
Inputs: ${inputs}
<br/>
Result: ${result}
</body>
```

Instead of explicitly listing the variables, how can I just loop through the keys and values of my `results` HashMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [c:forEach](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/iterate-hashmap-using-jstl-foreach/) tag and then just reference the `key` and `value` fields of each item.

```
<c:forEach var="result" items="${results}">
   Key: ${result.key}
   Value: ${result.value}
</c:forEach>
```

This will require a change in your controller:

```
 public ModelAndView testRoCompliance(@RequestParam String regOfficeStr) {
    Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();
    results.put("inputs", "an input");
    results.put("result", "the answer");
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("simpleOutput");
    modelAndView.addObject("results", results);
    return modelAndView;  
 }
```

Comment: That is helpful, but doesn't quite work for me.  ${results} is not bound to anything.  Is there some kind of auto-instantiated session variable or something that I should be using instead?

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  I'm curious.  ModelAndView has a  getModel() method that returns a Map<String,Object>.  Is there any way to obtain that Map via some auto-instantiated variable, or must I always provide some kind of hard-coded name to reference, e.g., "results"?